Python Project import structure
I am currently working on a Python Project in VSCode and after several hours of work I am wondering how I can improve my import structure.
Currently I have the following structure:
\API
---\__init__.py (empty)
---\Bot.py
---\Helper.py
---\NetworkManager.py
---\DatabaseManager.py
Helper.py acts as a central module that contains many imports such as json, datetime as well as central functions and classes that are used in the other modules.
Of course, not every function/class from Helper is used everywhere in the other modules.
The imports in the modules look like this:
Bot.py

from Helper import *
from NetworkManager import *
from DatabaseManager import *

NetworkManager.py

from Helper import *

DatabaseManager.py

from Helper import *

I am aware that import * is not a best practice. But because I take care to name functions/classes/attributes uniquely,
a) I don't run into namespace problems
b) I can simply import helpers wherever I need some elements from them and don't have to worry about selecting exactly what I really need. This makes it really relaxed in terms of import handling during development
Nevertheless, I have the feeling that this is unattractive and perhaps even inefficient and of course I want to develop my programming skills further, hence the question:
“What are your suggestions to improve the import structure, but at the same time keep the mentioned advantages b) more or less in the development?”

"because I take care to name functions/classes/attributes uniquely" Many things work well for such small home project, of course. When you work with a team of coders on a project with 10_000+ lines of code, things like import * will get much more messy.

I usually develop a lot of microservices and APIs for personal and professional work. Here is my go-to file structure.
More or less has been quite efficient for most of the smaller APIs.
my_api_project/
├── app/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py 
│   ├── config/
│   ├── api/
│   │   ├── v1/
│   │   │   ├── endpoints/
│   │   │   └── models/
│   │   └── utils/
│   ├── core/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── security.py 
│   │   ├── auth.py 
│   │   └── database.py 
│   ├── schemas/
│   ├── services/
│   ├── tests/
│   │   └── utils/
└── Dockerfile 
└── docker-compose.yml  
└── requirements.txt 
└── .env   
└── README.md 
└── .gitignore 


